# Non abelian Lie group with abelian Lie algebra

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples

I've been trying to find an example of a non abelian, non connected Lie group such that its Lie algebra is abelian but I can't find one, so can somenone please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take *any* Abelian Lie group $G$ and consider $G\times S_3$. You can use any other non-Abelian discrete group instead of $S_3$. Anyway, the Lie algebra of $G\times S_3$ is (isomorphic to) the Lie algebra of $G$, which is Abelian.

Comment: I don't understand how to give $G\times S_3$ a structure of smooth manifold

Comment: The group $S_3$ has $6$ elements, right?! So, as far as the manifold structure is concerned, it's as if you had $G\times\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. You have $6$ copies of $G$: $G\times\{0\},G\times\{1\},\ldots,G\times\{5\}$, each of which inherits a manifold structure from $G$.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not required to be connected, this is easy. Let $H$ be a finite nonabelian group and consider $S^1\times H$. This has an abelian Lie algebra but is not abelian.